# sql query select conditioned

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to write a sql query from transactional data set (custid, supplierid, transactionid, date). I want to find by custID the supplier with whom max transactions happened and supplier with whom recent transaction happened?

Input

```
custID - supplierid - transactionid - date
1      - a          - 1111a         - 9/22/2017
1      - a          - 1111b         - 9/23/2017
1      - a          - 1111c         - 9/24/2017
1      - b          - 1111d         - 9/21/2017
1      - c          - 1111e         - 9/25/2017
```

Desired

```
custID - suppliermax - supplierrcnt - datercnt
1      - a           - c            - 9/25/2017
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: You should probably specify which SQL DB you're using, as it has impact especially for the `date` field. e.g. PostgreSQL supports native timestamp types, but SQLite stores timestamps typically as strings or ints.

Comment: The data is hosted in netezza and connected through SQuirrel SQL Client. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return more rows if you have more suppliers with a maximal number of transactions. Moreover, it assumes that there is always just one `supplierrcnt` supplier.

```
 SELECT <input_id> AS custid, 
    supplierid AS suppliermax, 
    (
       SELECT supplierid
       FROM tab
       WHERE datercnt = (SELECT MAX(datercnt) FROM tab WHERE custID  = <input_id>)
       LIMIT 1
    ) AS supplierrcnt,
    (SELECT MAX(datercnt) FROM tab WHERE custID  = <input_id>) AS datercnt
 FROM tab
 WHERE custID  = <input_id>
 GROUP BY supplierid
 HAVING count(*) >= ALL(
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM tab
   WHERE custID  = <input_id>
   GROUP BY supplierid
 )
```

Comment: From the question I think he wants to aggregate by cust_id, even though the sample only provided one distinct value.

Comment: @Error_2646 The `cust_id` is the input. The aggregation in my solution is done to find the supplier with the highest number of transactions (for that customer)

Comment: I know in your solution the cust_id is input, but would require a manually input or cursor rather than just simple aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Neteeza, but I'm pretty sure it supports analytical functions like this.

```
SELECT cust_id,
       MAX(
         CASE WHEN suppRN = 1 THEN supplier 
              ELSE NULL
          END
          ) AS supplierMax,
       MAX(
         CASE WHEN tran_rn = 1 THEN supplier 
              ELSE NULL
          END
          ) AS supplierrCnt,         
       MAX(
         CASE WHEN tran_rn = 1 THEN date_
              ELSE NULL
          END
          ) AS datercnt
  FROM (SELECT cust_id,
               supplier,
               date_,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY cust_id
                       ORDER BY suppCnt DESC
                 ) AS suppRN,
               tran_rn
          FROM (SELECT cust_id,
                       supplier,
                       COUNT(*) OVER
                         ( PARTITION BY cust_id,
                                        supplier
                         ) AS suppCnt,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                         ( PARTITION BY cust_id
                               ORDER BY date_ DESC
                         ) AS tran_rn
                  FROM Customer
               ) AS TMP
       ) AS TMP2
 WHERE suppRN = 1
    OR tran_rn = 1       
 GROUP
    BY cust_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have customized and tested and it is working.